# how disable http access in couchdb

Tags: ssl, couchdb

I'm using CouchdDB on MacOSX El Captain and trying to use https. Adaptations in the local.ini file are:
    [ssl]
    verify_ssl_certificates = false
    ssl_certificate_max_depth = 1
    cert_file = /opt/local/etc/couchdb/certs/localhost.crt
    key_file = /opt/local/etc/couchdb/certs/localhost.key
    port = 6984

But in how far can I prevent access through the 5984 port?

Answer (score 1):

Under [daemons], remove (if it is there, or comment it out):

```
httpd={couch_httpd, start_link, []}
```

and put in,

```
httpsd = {couch_httpd, start_link, [https]}
```

Then, restart couchdb.

Comment: The above only adds https to CouchDB, but does not disable http

Answer (score 0):

You can disable access to the http port 5984 via your firewall.

For example, in CentOS,

```
iptables --append INPUT --protocol tcp --sport 5984 --dport 5984 --jump DROP
```

Same idea can be applied to every OS. In MacOS, you can block the port using the System Preferences > Security > Firewall user interface.